# Unix Script Shell

Tags: shell, unix, monitoring

Could any one Help me with the script

Im trying to make a script shell that will alerts/email the root if any of those files has been modified and the script has to auto routine , so the script have to be running at all time

I'm tried doing something to start with but i need some one to correct me or give me ideas

```
#!/bin/bash

if [`find . -mtime -0` -eq date];then
    mail -s "modified files" root
    find  /etc/passwd /etc/shadow /etc/group /etc/gshadow /etc/sudoers /etc/hosts /etc/sysconfig/network /etc/resolv.conf /etc/bashrc /etc/fstab -type f -mtime -50
else
    mail -s "nothing" root
fi
```

Comment: I'm doing this for a school assignment and I'm not allowed to install any programs, it has to be build in and used only terminal with a file name extension ./File.Sh

Comment: What's the idea with the `find /etc...-type f -mtime -50`? Did you intend to mail its output? If so, you should pipe it to `mail`. Otherwise it would only be printed on standard output.

Comment: You're not allowed to install any programs, but you are allowed to ask Stack Overflow to do the assignment for you? Interesting rules.

Comment: @wooble its a script that i tried doing and someone corrected me ,and not doing it , and yes not allowed to install any programs

Comment: @wooble but it was nice of you to help

Answer (score 0):

You could put your `if` statement within a loop that would sleep some time between iterations:

```
#!/bin/bash

while sleep 10; do
    # Your "if" goes here 
    # it will be executed with 10 second sleep between iterations.
    if [...]
       ...
    fi
done
```

Comment: i just want to be make a shell script that will email the root if any of the files listed above have been modified

Comment: I'm doing this for a school assignment and I'm not allowed to install any programs, it has to be build in and used only terminal with a file name extension ./File.Sh

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you need to figure out how to make the script to perform the checks periodically? If so, see my answer above. `while` is a shell keyword and `sleep` is either a shell built-in or a standard utility, so you don't need to install anything.

Comment: don't use `[ ... ]`.  It's [deprecated syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).  _Only_ use `[ ... ]` or `test <TEST>` when `[[ ... ]]` is _not_ available, as in when using `dash` instead of `bash`.

Comment: I understand what your are trying to explain but I'm not sure if the code that i have is working , i just need someone to correct me or give me a similar answer to mine , or a full script that will do what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script (a.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

date=1
file=$(find . -mtime -${date})

if [  "${file}X" != "X" ]; then
  echo "$file" |mail -s "modified files" root
fi
```

Put the script in cronjob, for example, run every 10 minutes:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * bash a.sh
```

the cornjob will keep monitoring the file updated status, and you needn't care it with  more scripting in while loop.

Comment: Better to use `a != b` than `! a = b`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the specific answers with pointers to resources:

Some resources to **get started** with `bash`:

- Introduction to `bash`: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html
- Cheat sheet: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet

Here are two helpful **resources for experimenting**:

- http://shellcheck.net can help you **find syntax errors in your shell code** - while a great resource, it can't detect *all* problems in your code, however. It would, however, detect one problem with your `[ ... ]` conditional.
- http://explainshell.com is a great site that **explains a given command line** based on `man` pages; for instance, here is the explanation for `find . -mtime -0`: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.+-mtime+-0 - note that the underlying `man` pages are Ubuntu's, so they cover *GNU* utilities, which many, but not all Unix distributions use; GNU utilities often have helpful, but non-standard extensions that may not be available on some platforms (e.g., OSX).